# Passing parameters to Anonymous function inside click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
var div_raw_id = 'acf-download-link';
var div_id = '#' + div_raw_id; 
var chapter_index = 1;
var chapter = 'chapter-' + chapter_index;

$('button[name=addnewchapter]').click(function(chapter, div_id ,div_raw_id){
    $(div_id).append('<div class="acf-input-wrap"><input id="' + div_raw_id +'" class="text" name="fields[field_55951fb44c1d6][' + chapter + '][]" value="" placeholder="" type="text"><span class="remove_btn"></span></div>');
    return false;
});
```

The problem is  I cannot pass `div_id`, `chapter_index`, `chapter` as a parameter to the anonymous function inside the click event. I used the debugger and the debugger represents them as undefined values even though they are defined in above code. It seems there is a variable scope problem, however, I cannot figure out any other way to pass the defined variables as a parameter to the anonymous function inside the click event.

Comment: You don't have to pass it as arguments in the function. Just use the variables it inside

Comment: I think you don't need to pass them as argument. Just use them directly in function. Since they are defined in global scope

Comment: @MikeBoutin I have included the code. I am just trying to append an input field into my form whenever the button is clicked, what is confusing you exactly?

Comment: [`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) -> `data`: "Data to be passed to the handler in event.data when an event is triggered."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to pass the variables defined at the beginning as parameters, simply use it inside the function:

```
var div_raw_id = 'acf-download-link';
var div_id = '#' + div_raw_id; 
var chapter_index = 1;
var chapter = 'chapter-' + chapter_index;

$('button[name=addnewchapter]').click(function(){
    $(div_id).append('<div class="acf-input-wrap"><input id="' + div_raw_id +'" class="text" name="fields[field_55951fb44c1d6][' + chapter + '][]" value="" placeholder="" type="text"><span class="remove_btn"></span></div>');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: And this works because those variables have been captured in a closure by the anonymous function.

Comment: Doh! I am awfully thankful. I am just new to javascript. I am wondering why such thing would be allowed, are we allowed to use outside of function defined variables inside the newly created function, why such thing is allowed?

Comment: @FreeMind - Read about closures.

Comment: This may not be the answer you want, you have access to the variables, but the values of those variables are not fixed to the values you might think.  Try adding the statement  chapter = 'chappie -' + chapter_index after the definition of the click and then click the button.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass anything (no string as it would be used as selector, preferable an object) you want to your event handler.

See the documentation of [`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for further infos on the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/) parameter

```
var eventData = {
    "div_id": "acf-download-link"
    ,"chapter": 1
};

$('button[name=addnewchapter]').on("click", eventData, function(e){
    $("#" + e.data.div_id)
        .append('<div class="acf-input-wrap"><input id="' + e.data.div_id + '"'
                + ' class="text" name="fields[field_55951fb44c1d6][chapter-' + e.data.chapter + '][]"'
                + ' value="" placeholder="" type="text"><span class="remove_btn"></span></div>');

    return false;
});
```

Comment: What is that `e` parameter passed to the anonymous function? How should I know that I have to pass such mysterious arguments?

Comment: The registered event handler will always be passed an [event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event) object as the first parameter -> [Document Object Model Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Registration-interfaces-h3). This is also mentioned in the documentation of the `.on()` method

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [JS Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) Your click handler is defined at the same level as the variables `div_raw_id, div_id, div_raw_id, chapter_index, chapter`.

This means that if you give the callback function arguments with the same name the callback function can no longer see the external ones with the same name.

So `chapter_index` Should still be defined. The first argument `chapter` will be the first parameter that jQuery passes through (The Event Object) the last 2 will be set to `undefined`.